# Foundation 5: Dropdown content not working

Tags: zurb-foundation

I am trying content dropdown from Foundation 5: http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/dropdown.html, but it does not work as you can see on this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AQGd9/2/. Basically, the content does not appear upon clicking the link when it should.

```
<a href="#" data-dropdown="drop2">Has Content Dropdown</a>
    <ul id="drop2" class="f-dropdown content" data-dropdown-content>
      <li><a href="#">This is a link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">This is another</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Yet another</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Thanks

Comment: make sure that you have properly included the required foundation js files

Comment: also you dont need foundation.dropdown.js if you are using foundation.min.js

Comment: Did you ever figure this problem out?  I'm having the same problem.

Answer (score 6):

You need to explicitly initialize foundation with this piece of code before the end of your `body`, like this:

```
<body>
  ...
  <script>
    $(document).foundation();
  </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 4):

I have the same problem right now. The doc says that you need include the javascript required files, there are two ways to do it:

1) All Js (core + plugins): foundation.min.js

2) Only the core, and add the plugins on demand: foundation.js + foundation.dropdown.js (in this case).

So, launch foundation Js:

```
$(document).foundation();
```

Source: [Foundation 5 Js Doc](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/javascript.html)

This work for me.

Comment: 2) + foundation.topbar.js (in some other cases)